# Socket closed error in Google Storage SDK in DataFlow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using google-cloud-storage (1.54.0) in my DataFlow pipeline(2.29.0) to write files to Google Storage.
I see the below error randomly.

Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Socket closed org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:187) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:108) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1058) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:445) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:130) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1061) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:932)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using google-cloud-storage directly rather Dataflow's built in write-to-GCS operations?

Comment: because I want to determine the path to write the file to on run time.

Answer (score 0):

When running a distributed system, especially at scale, you need to be able to handle transient errors (as well as idempotence in the face of retry).